# Get domains(address) IP with a HTML form

Tags: php, forms, post, ip, gethostbyname

I am trying to do a script thats a user put the address or domain in the area input and the script turns back the ip of the same address/domain.

But the script is crapping all time, I've tried to copy the same is on my contact-form.php but is not working; someone can help me? The post method is not working good.

Thanks all

```
<form id="host" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>" method="post" name="host">
<input type="text" placeholder="Address/host.." name="domain" size="14" maxlength="63" value="<?php echo (isset($_POST['host'])) ? $_POST['host'] : ""; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="&#x2714;" />
</form> 
<?php 

$host = $_POST['host'];

$ip = gethostbyname($host);

echo "Ip is : $ip \n";

?>
```

Comment: Define 'crapping out all the time'?

Answer (score 1):

Well, your `action` should just be `""` or `"contact-form.php"`.   Your `$host` has to point to your POST value of `domain`.  Once you correct those two errors your form should work.

Comment: Thanks for you care but the error remains ( undefined index ); should i put htmlentities to get the $_POST area?

Comment: To fix an undefined index error, just declare your variable.  So at the top of your php, put the variable name = "".  Example: `$host = "";`

Comment: You should do the same for `$ip = "";`

Answer (score 0):

your field name is `domain`, form name is `host`, so you do this:

```
$host = $_POST['domain'];
```

Edit :

```
<?
if(isset($_POST['domain'])){
  $host = $_POST['domain'];
  $ip = gethostbyname($host);
  echo "Ip is : $ip \n"; 
}
?>

<form id="host" method="post">
<input type="text" placeholder="Address/host.." name="domain" size="14" maxlength="63" ><input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks Pheonix, -1 error, now the server says this error:
Notice: Undefined index: domain on line 41
the line 41 is: $host = $_POST['domain']; /* your answer */ 

:-s i really don't know whats happening

Comment: Ah, you give me the code, i really glad you :-)! I'll not copy, but look and try to found the error! Thanks Pheonix.